# Is the Sample in https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot Secure?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-keyvault

The [readme](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-sample/README.md) describes placing a service principle's ID and secret in the properties. Is this not counter to using a key vault to store your secrets? Or am I reading this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the sample, it exposes the `client id` and `client secret` in the `application.properties`.

If you want to use the sample in the production environment in azure, the best practice is to use the [MSI(managed identity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview), then it is no need to expose the id and secret in the `application.properties`, just enable the MSI and add it to the keyvault access policy, it supports the Azure Spring Cloud, App Service, VM.

Reference - https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/master/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter/README.md#use-msi--managed-identities

Answer (score 0):

But the real question is what to do if you do not want to use MSI, giving key, tenant & enable = false does not works. As in above reference.